# How do I get my age in X days using Moment.js?

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

My current code is

```
function ageInNDays(days) {
  return moment.duration(
    moment('1990-10-10').diff(
    moment().add(days, 'days'))
  );
}
```

I `.add(days, 'days')` to today, then diff it against some date in the past. However, `moment.duration` doesn't exactly always return the number of calendar years that pass. It defines a year as 365 days and returns how many of those years have passed.

EDIT: I'm still looking for my age as a number of Years. Maybe if possible, something like 20 Years, 5 Months, and 10 Days format similar to how moment.duration() looks.

If my birthday is March 5th 1992, then my age should only increment when the calendar passes March 5th. My remainder age in days should only reset when the 5th of every month passes.

EDIT2: My only idea now is something like

```
age = moment().add(days, 'days').year() - moment('1995-01-05').year()
if ((today's date + added days) < birthday's date)
  --age
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/),

> Trying to convert years to days makes no sense without context. It is much better to use moment#diff for calculating days or years between two moments than to use Durations.

So it looks like using [diff](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) is the answer:

```
function ageInNDays(days) { 
    return moment().add(days, 'days').diff('1990-10-10', 'years', true); 
}

// ageInNDays(1000);
// 27.977483271480484
```

Note that gives you the fractional number of years (by virtue of the third argument). You could truncate that if you don't want it rounded (which the default implementation does):

```
function ageInNDays(days) { 
    return Math.floor(moment().add(days, 'days').diff('1990-10-10', 'years', true)) + ' years'; 
}

// ageInNDays(1000);
// 27 years
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're really looking for age in days, you can use:

```
moment.duration(moment() - moment('1990-10-10')).asDays();
```

**UPDATE**

You can also use this to add days to your current age:

```
function ageInNDays(days) {
    var age = moment.duration(moment() - moment('1990-10-10'));
    return age.add(days, 'd').asDays();
}
```

Comment: Sorry it's not "what is my age as a number of days" but "what will my age be N days from now"

Comment: @user1778856 - I've updated my answer. All you have to do is use the same base calculation and then add days to it...

Comment: Sorry, this still doesn't exactly answer my question. I will clarify shortly

Answer (score 0):

Add param boolean true for decimals diferency

```
var currentDate = new Date();
var diff = moment(currentDate).diff('1990-10-10', 'years',true);
console.log("Year", diff);
```

Example

That will answer 21.23 depending on the date